# Unable to download Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image for Android "Q"

Tags: android-studio

I'm getting below issue when i want to download "Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image" for "Q" version from SDK manager.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Android Studio 3.3.2, you may be running into [this bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129801155), which has not yet been resolved.